# SQLite query throwing exception in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to get an object form my SQLite database in my Android application. I know that the contact is in the database because when I add it and try finding by ID, it returns the object. When I try finding by first and last name, though, it throws an exception and Im left with a null reference. Here is the query:

```
cursor = mDb.query(DB_CONTACTS_NAME,
    new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                 KEY_ORGANIZATION_NAME, KEY_LABEL, KEY_LABEL_POSITION},
    KEY_FIRST_NAME + "=" + first + " AND " + KEY_LAST_NAME + "=" + last,
    null, null, null, null
);
```

Ive also tried to find just by first name and just by last name. Same result as above.

Edit: The exception is an SQLite exception

```
no such column: aurelius: , while compiling: SELECT _id, last_name, first_name,
email_address, organization_name, label, label_position FROM contacts WHERE
first_name=marcus AND last_name=aurelius
```

And also happens when trying to select just first or last name

```
no such column: marcus: , while compiling: SELECT _id, last_name, first_name,
email_address, organization_name, label, label_position FROM contacts WHERE
first_name=marcus
```

Comment: What is the exception type and message?

Comment: Alrighty, just edited the question to clarify on that. Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the literal strings. This should work:

```
cursor = mDb.query(DB_CONTACTS_NAME,
    new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                 KEY_ORGANIZATION_NAME, KEY_LABEL, KEY_LABEL_POSITION},
    KEY_FIRST_NAME + "='" + first + "' AND " + KEY_LAST_NAME + "='" + last + "'",
    null, null, null, null
);
```

Otherwise when the SQL interpreter see's

```
first_name=marcus
```

You cannot expect it to know that 'marcus' is not a table name or a variable.

On a side note try searching for the last name **"Billy" "); drop table contacts;"**

[DO NOT CONSTRUCT SQL QUERIES FROM DATA STRINGS](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Instead use a query which takes in an argument list. Search the docs for something like

```
String[] myArguments = new String[] {first, last};
cursor = mDb.query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?;", myArguments);
```

This is much safer. In your version if the 'first' or 'last' variables contain control characters which SQLite interprets as commands then you may break your database system. **DO NOT DO IT** ... **EVER**

Comment: You sir, are correct. I never thought I would be the one to make that mistake after I read that comic a while back, but alas, I did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the answer!  I wish I had the points to vote this up!  Specifically, the strings of the WHERE clause have to have the single quotes around them:

KEY_FIRST_NAME + "='" + first + "' AND " + KEY_LAST_NAME + "='" + last + "'"